# Android WebView goBack not working for post request

Tags: android, post, webview, browser-history

I overrided onFormResubmission function in my WebClient. However, when hitting goBack to a page from post request, it will show 'WebPage not available' still.

Anyone has an idea over this? Thanks!

```
    private class NormalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend) {
            resend.sendToTarget();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the cache mode seems to work around this issue:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Saw this on some other threads and it worked for me.  For information's sake, the "WebPage not available" behavior doesn't happen on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.2 but it does happen on a Samsung S4 running Android 4.4.2.  I'm not sure yet whether the relevant factor is OS version or device.